Laravel controller not recieving the data sent from form
When trying to send data from a searchbar form to a route controller the data cannot be reached by using the $request->input("name"). How can i fix this?
Controller
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    function search(Request $request){
        if(empty($request->input("search"))){
            return view("search", ["results" => [], "searchTerm" => ""]);
        }
        else{
            $searchTerm = $request->input("search");
            $papers = Papers::where("title", "like", "%".$searchTerm."%")
            ->orWhere("author", "like", "%".$searchTerm."%")
            ->orWhere("tags", "like", "%".$searchTerm."%")
            ->get();
            return view("search", ["results" => $papers, "searchTerm" => $searchTerm])->with("data", $request->input());
        }
    }
}

Form
<form class="form-search flex-center w100" method="GET" action="{{route("search")}}">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Sök..." value="{{empty($search) ? "" : $search}}">
    <button id="submit" for="submit">
        <span class="shadow"></span>
        <span class="edge"></span>
        <span class="front flex-center"><img src="{{asset("svg/search.svg")}}" alt="search icon svg"> Sök</span>
    </button>
</form>

Route
use App\Http\Controllers\LandingController;
use App\Http\Controllers\SearchController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get("/", [LandingController::class, "index"])->name("home");

Route::get('/search', [SearchController::class, 'search'])->name('search');

I have tried changing the input to a query and i have used data dumps which gives me "[]" when on the input or query of the request and shows this when on the $request:
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/search"
  #requestUri: "/search?search=Repellat+sint+autem+facilis+odit."
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "GET"
  #format: null
  #session: 
Illuminate\Session\SymfonySessionDecorator {#278 ▶}
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -preferredFormat: null
  -isHostValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  -isSafeContentPreferred: ? bool
  -trustedValuesCache: []
  -isIisRewrite: false
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure($guard = null) {#237 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure() {#246 ▶}
  basePath: ""
  format: "html"


Have you tried to call dd($request->input()); and see the output?

@Frnak Yeah it's just an empty array.

Try to look in the developer tools of your browser what your request actually sends.

You are sending post data to a route that is defined as a GET route.
Change your route:
Route::post('/search', [SearchController::class, 'search'])->name('search');

And your form:
<form class="form-search flex-center w100" action="{{route("search")}}" method="POST">

and add a CSRF token to the form
{{ csrf_field() }}


Where do you see post data being sent? The method of the form is GET

Why would you send form data through GET routes? That's not what they are designed for.

What do you mean not designed for? The method doesn't matter you can send data in any kind of request. And he is asking for how to do it in a get. I think doing it via get is totally valid for a search, as a search could also be called directly via a link in order to send pre filtered results.

Yeah i want it to be a GET for that exact reason but even when changing it to a POST it still does not work. The data just gets lost somewhere. dd returns empty arrays.
